# UILabels have Faint Borders

Tags: ios, uilabel, border, calayer

I thought the default was a border width of 0.0. So I'm surprised I'm seeing boarders around my UILabels. I even tried using a CALayer to set the border to 0.0 and to set it to white, but I still see faint outlines. Here's my code.

```
-(UIView *)calendarDay:(int)d date:(NSDate *)date width:(float)w height:(float)h
{
//d is the day number in the month of the 28/293 calendar. It should display in bold in the upper, left.
//date is the date of that day. It should display in the upper, right.
//w is the width of the UIView in which to insert the labels.
//h is the height of the UIView in which to insert the labels.
//First create an outer view with a red background color.
UIView *frameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
[frameView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//Next decrease the width and height slightly to make a smaller view that fits inside the larger one.
w = w*0.98;
h = h*0.98;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd "];
UILabel *dayNumber = [[UILabel alloc] init];
dayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",d];
dayNumber.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
dayNumber.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,w/2,h/5);
dayNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UILabel *gregDate = [[UILabel alloc] init];
gregDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
gregDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
gregDate.frame = CGRectMake(w/2,0,w/2,h/5);
gregDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Following three lines were an attempt to make the borders disappear. It made no difference.

```
CALayer *gregDateLayer = [gregDate layer];
[gregDateLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[gregDateLayer setBorderWidth:0.0];

[gregDate setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
CGRect dayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
UIView *dayToReturn = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:dayRect];
[dayToReturn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
dayNumber.center = CGPointMake(w/4 ,h/4);
gregDate.center = CGPointMake(w*3/4,h/4);
[dayToReturn addSubview:dayNumber];
[dayToReturn addSubview:gregDate];
[frameView addSubview:dayToReturn];
dayToReturn.center = frameView.center;
return frameView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are thinking is a border is actually the background color of the UILabel.

Set the background color of your UILabels to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: That did it. I wonder why whiteColor didn't work. White on white is white just like clear on white is white. Or maybe not. Maybe there's some shadow rendering going on that doesn't happen with clear?